# Generate a new text using the style of one text and the nouns/verbs of another?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, markov-chains

I want to generate plausible (or less than plausible is okay too) nonsense text similar to the way that a [markov chain approach would do](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~cz1/prog/markov/markov.html), but I want the nouns and verbs of the generated text to come from a different source than the analyzed text.

So, for example, let's say that text 1 is from [Little Red Riding Hood](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11592/11592-h/11592-h.htm), and my list of nouns/verbs is something like the ones listed here: [nouns](http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-nouns.html), [verbs](http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-verbs.html).  I'm looking for a way to swap out some/all of the nouns/verbs in text 1 with the new nouns/verbs. Then I would generate a new text from the mashup (perhaps using the markov chain approach).

I'm guessing that I need some sort of initial grammar analysis for text 1, and then perhaps do a swap with appropriately coded words of the insertion noun/verb lists?

Comment: making some progress on a possible solution. right now i'm looking at using the natural language toolkit (NLTK) to tokenize and tag the source text. then i'll see, once I've tagged nouns and verbs, if I can programmatically substitute my own set of nouns/verbs into the original.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with text generation but I'd suggest a [language modelling](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/) approach. You should check out the first 1-2 lectures for inspiration :)

You can try creating a language model, independent on the nouns and verbs (i.e. replacing them with _noun and _verb). Then you can try generating text from it, based on a factor of randomness since the suggested model just counts words and phrases.

I haven't tried it and I hope it works for you.